# How to trace connections from users on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

I'm setting up a new AgensGraph server, and want to trace connections from user.

Also how much times they spend.

Answer (score 0):

You can try connection log of AgensGraph.

First, change parameters on "postgresql.conf"

```
log_connections = on
log_disconnections = on
log_line_prefix = '[%c] '
```

Second, restart AgensGraph.

```
$ ag_ctl stop
waiting for server to shut down.... done
server stopped
$ ag_ctl start
server starting
```

Finally, make connections and check log file.

```
$ agens
agens (AgensGraph 1.3.1, based on PostgreSQL 9.6.2)
Type "help" for help.

agens=# \quit
```

You can get information about host, user and duration of connections.

```
[5c456a09.dc2] LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
[5c456a09.dc2] LOG:  connection authorized: user=agens database=agens
[5c456a09.dc2] LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:07.626 user=agens database=agens host=[local]
```